# Dealing with race conditions between valueChange and afterScriptsLoaded and init

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Say I have good chunk of scripts that take a while to load and a `aura:handler name="change"`.

How do I ensure that when record changes, the scripts are there to use?

**Edit**:

Scenario one:

ComponentA loads on a detail page, fires navigateToComponent( ComponentB). AfterScriptsLoaded on ComponentB doesn't fire so my logic cannot execute. However, what I found accidentally, by using init handler I can found that my library is indeed loaded!

So by doing simple check `if(myLibraryName)` when init runs on normal page load, I can work around this bug until it will be quietly fixed and break it...

In regards valueChange, it fires before afterScriptsLoaded, not sure what workaround is viable here.

p.s. a trick for young players - see how your app behaves when `Disable cache` is enabled in Chrome.

Comment: I think the scripts once loaded is available for you and can interact automatically even on change events .Do you have specific example here ?

Comment: make afterScriptsLoaded controller function set a flag such as `scriptsLoaded` and then have checks in your handler that this flag is true.

Comment: When practical, simply show a spinner until the scripts are loaded, and then allow the user to interact with the page.

Comment: Another annoyance is when using navigateToComponent event, if scripts are cached already by an extended component - afterScriptsLoaded event is not fired at all.

Comment: @dzh I don't think that's right. I'm pretty sure that I've seen the opposite behaviour. If something else has already loaded the scripts, then afterScriptsLoaded fires immediately. Which can break things if you were relying on it happening later (e.g. after rendering) and didn't have flags to track what was happening